# I need to edit and clear out obstruction in my recording

Tags: audio-recording, audio-restoration

I have a recording from my IPhone it needs to be more clear. It was 26 min long and I downloaded it on a equalizer app I played with vocal spore and I need help cleaning out background noise and making all vocals clear.

Comment: What exactly are you wanting from us? Recommendations for software, or a technique? Are you going to transfer this to a computer? If so, what OS? Software recommendations should really be posted on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ rather than here, but you will have to provide substantially more detail as to what you need.

Comment: A technique pls

Comment: To recommend a technique, we first need to know what the actual issue is, in detail, including samples of the audio. It will *still* involve a software purchase, & transfer to computer, as I know of nothing for a mobile device that can broad-spectrum noise kill. You're going to be looking at something like [Izotope RX](https://www.izotope.com/en/products/rx.html) or trying to find some cheaper alternative [which I've never really investigated, RX is king in this field]

Comment: If you have no clue where to start, you might be better off paying someone to do it.